# How can I destructure my array of multiple objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

```
  [
    0: {_id: '61de38eb6ea1563609e1d0a7', title: 'FALCON SR SUNTOUR', price: '59', description: ' Alloy.., …}
    1: {_id: '61d7a8b885c68311be8dd1b3', title: 'Lifelong LLBC2702 Falcon', price: '59', description: 'Low Maintenance: High.., …}
    ]
```

I am creating a react project. I have the above array of objects on my database.  If any user place order the order list and user email will go into a single array. So my question is how can I display the orders. I have tried a map also tried a nested map but got " order.map is not a function". Here is the code

```
{orders.map((order, idx) => order.map(singleOrder => console.log(singleOrder)))}
```

I want to destructure the order details into UI

This is my code:

```
const ManageAllOrders = () => {
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])
    const { user } = UseAuth()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://polar-savannah-40370.herokuapp.com/dashboard/orders`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setOrders(data))
    }, [user.email])

    console.log('orders', orders);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Manage Orders</h2>
            <Table responsive striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Order Date</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        orders?.map((order, idx) =>
                            Object.defineProperties(order).map(([key, value]) => {
                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        {key} : {value}
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        )}

                    {/* {orders.map((order, idx) => order[0].map(console.log()))} */}

                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ManageAllOrders;
```

Comment: you data is not a valid JS array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `map` on each order item as it is an `object`. To iterate over them use `Object.entries` method.

Try like below

```
{
    orders?.map((order, idx) =>
        Object.entries(order).map(
            ([key, { description, title, price, cartQuantity }]) => {
                if (key !== "_id") {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{key}</td>
                            <td>{title}</td>
                            <td>{price}</td>
                            <td>{cartQuantity}</td>
                            <td>{description}</td>
                            <td>email</td>
                            <td>address</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

I also noticed your array has stored values with string keys (`email`, `_id`). To retrieve them you can do it like below.

```
{orders?.["email"]}
{orders?.["_id"]}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-shtern-ccen6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Fathe Karim, check this out!! Let me know if you still get any errors

Comment: it's Not working, I am getting this error " Cannot convert undefined or null to object "

Comment: @FatheKarim, updated the answer with the optional chaining operator (`?.`)? can you check again? I guess `console.log(orders)` is the array you have attached ?

Comment: still getting the same error and it's the same array. I have updated my question can you check, please.

Answer (score 0):

Is Data type Array??

```
    useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://polar-savannah-40370.herokuapp.com/dashboard/orders`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setOrders(data))
}, [user.email])
```